# Regex-Match while ignoring a char from Searchword

Tags: regex

I am using an Engineering Program which lets me Code formulas in order to filter out specific lines in a database. I am trying to look for a certain line in the database which contains e.g. "concrete" as a property.

In the Code I can use regular expressions.

The regex I was using so far looked like this:

```
".*(concrete).*";
```

so if the line in the database contains concrete, I will get the wanted result.
Now the Problem is: i would like to switch the word concrete with a variable, so that it Looks like this:

```
".*(@VARIABLE1).*";
```

(the Syntax with the @ works in the program btw.)
the Problem is: if i set the variable as concrete, the program automatically switches it for `'concrete'` . Obviously, the word concrete cant be found anymore, since the searchterm now contains the two ' Symbols in the beginning and i the end.

Is there a way to ignore those two characters using the Right regex?

what I want it to do is the following:
If a line in the database contains "25cm concrete in Grey"
I should get a match from the regex.
with the searchterm `".*(concrete).*";` it works, with the variable `".*(@VARIABLE1).*";` it doesnt.

EDIT:

the whole "Formula" in the program Looks like that:

```
if(Match(QTO(Typ:="Attribut{FloorsLayer_02_MaterialName}");".*(@V_QUALITY).*" ;"regex") ;QTO(Typ:="Attribut{Fläche}");0)
```

I want the if-condition to be true, when the match inside is true.
the whole QTO function is just the programs Syntax to use a certain Attribute into the match-function, the middle part is my Problem. I really don't know the programming language or anything,I'm new to this. hope it helps!

Comment: Do you use some programming language? The regex could be compiled beforehand than.

Comment: You can concatenate the pattern string. Something like ".*(" + variable1 + ")*.".

Comment: @Jan I am not sure, but I guess SQL. I am only using the Front end of an Engineering Program and cant really find out anything About whats going on in the backend.....

@robert somehow I'm not allowed to use the two " " inside the brackets, the + alone didn't work.

@Burdui I can type in the string in VARIABLE 1, but when i type e.g. `concrete` i can see that it sets it as `'concrete'` inside the Formula, so i Need to get rid of the two ' characters.

Comment: The syntax may be different depending on the programming language. It will help if you could post more code.

Comment: *"Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."* - [regex tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Comment: @robert sorry, but I really dont know. check my edit above, Maybe it helps!

Comment: Whats the name of the software?

Comment: @Burdui RIB iTWO, its a Program for mass calculations, the whole if/match constellation filters Building parts by e.g. material to automatically calculate its quantity

Comment: to your answer below: the string `(@VARIABLE1)` probably gets replaced by `('<Content of Variable 1>')` , it really just puts `' '` around whatever I type as the variable. I can only see what it _normally_ does, but not what it does in the regex-case, which is just possibly in the not so often used match-function for the program.

Answer (score 0):

Thats more of a hack than a real solution and i'm not sure if it even works:

if you use the regex

```
.*(@VARIABLE1)?).*
```

and the string `?concrete(`

this will result in a regex looking like this:

```
.*('?concrete(')?).*
```

which makes the additional characters optional.

---

This uses the following assumtption:

the string `(@VARIABLE1)` gets replaced by the `('<content of VARIABLE1>')`

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't work. I dont know if the program uses the variable as a string in the Formula or only the value I give to the variable, but it doesnt work.
edit:
i think the program used `VARIABLE1?` as the Name of the variable. putting it in brackets
  `".*((@V_QUALITY)?).*"` worked, but I guess that makes sense...

Comment: @Dom_K If i understood you correctly then the edited regex should work (without additional parenthesis).

Comment: doesnt work yet, but I guess we're getting Closer... i´cant find any Information what the program really does with what I type in, About the regex-syntax I only found 1 example:
`Match(TEXT;“.(e|u).“;“regex“)` 
and the info that regex is allowed in General. by that example, do you see what the program does when brackets are used?
Edit: the example gives a true when the string TEXT contains an e or u as second character.

Comment: @Dom_K But using ```.*((@V_QUALITY)?).*``` works as desired? Should i modify my answer to contain that regex?

Comment: Im sorry, @burdui I didnt write it exactly clear: putting it in brackets `".*((@V_QUALITY)?).*"` didn't quite work, it only made the whole variable optional, leading to a match for every single line, not only the ones with the Attribute concrete to them.

Comment: So it seems as if the Parenthesis are required for the variable substitution but are also included in the resulting string. Mmmmh....

Comment: @Dom_K i modified my answer, pls check

Comment: `".*@V_QUALITY ?.*"` does not work, `".*@V_QUALITY?.*"` makes the program think the var. Name is V_QUALITY? (EDIT: I guess it does…) and `".*(@V_QUALITY)?.*"` gives me matches for every line again.

Comment: also, if I type the regex you posted `.*(@VARIABLE1)?).*` with the value of the variable directly into the Formula, so `.*?'concrete'?.*` it somehow messes the whole Formula as soon as I save it (scrambled words and characters etc.) I guess the program just cant handle the ?, i dont know why…..

Comment: @Dom_K Did you add the opening bracket in the search-string? If not the regex will be invalid.

Comment: The bracket constellation you wrote did not work, since it Closes the Match function to early, I am not allowed to save that Formula in that way no matter the other bracket in the variables Name. I tried several other constellations, like `.*(@V_QUALITY)?.*` and some others, which just gave me all or no Matches, too. the one above gave me all Matches, which makes me think the ? still works on the whole variable, I'm really confused on how the Programm processes variables.....

Comment: @Dom_K I'm sorry i could not help you, did you find a solution though?